# Boost spirit parsing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to take a string and then retrieve the required elements from it. At the moment, I can't seem to find a way of doing it because the input string that will change from time to time, although the elements won't.

My code so far is below. What I want to do is extract the `'.V/'` from the string when parsed.

My code so far below will work, but I need it to be more generic as there are many elements within the inputted string

- i.e

  ```
  .V/ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN
  .E/45/SHAM/CAMP/2
  ```

  and I would need to retrieve `.V/` and `.E/`

```
std::vector<std::string>elements;
std::string input = ".V/ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN ";

bool result = qi::parse(input.begin(),input.end(),
        *(*(qi::char_ - " /ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN\n") >> " /ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN\n"),
        elements
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd really suggest using a regular expression (boost regex or std::regex) for this job.

The regular expression would probably look like

```
std::regex re("^(\\.[EV]/).*?$"); // the first submatch is the part you are looking for
```

Here is a bit of spirit in case you really need it:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>elements;
    std::string input = 
        ".V/ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN\n"
        ".E/45/SHAM/CAMP/2";

    It first(input.begin()), last(input.end());

    bool ok = qi::parse(first, last,
            (
              '.' > qi::char_("EV") > '/' 
                 >> qi::omit [ *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ] 
            ) % qi::eol,
            elements);

    if (ok)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<elements.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << elements[i] << std::endl;
    } else
    {
        std::cerr << "Parse failed at '" << std::string(first, last) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

This will output

```
V
E
```

If you want to show '.E/' there, there are many ways about it, e.g.

```
bool ok = qi::parse(first, last,
        (
          (qi::char_('.') > qi::char_("EV") > qi::char_('/' )
             >> qi::omit [ *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ] )
        ) % qi::eol,
        elements);
```

output:

```
.V/
.E/
```

### Bonus

To show how to include the 'tail' of the line, possibly storing into map:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> result_t;
    // or use a list to allow duplicate keys:
    // typedef std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > result_t;
    result_t mappings;

    std::string input = 
        ".V/ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN\n"
        ".E/45/SHAM/CAMP/2";

    It first(input.begin()), last(input.end());

    bool ok = qi::parse(first, last, (
                  qi::raw [ '.' > qi::char_("EV") > '/' ]
                > qi::raw [ *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ]
            ) % qi::eol,
            mappings);

    if (ok)
    {
        for (result_t::const_iterator it=mappings.begin();
             it!=mappings.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->first << " maps to " << it->second << std::endl;
        }
    } else
    {
        std::cerr << "Parse failed at '" << std::string(first, last) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

would output

```
.E/ maps to 45/SHAM/CAMP/2
.V/ maps to ER/12/FRG/45S/16JAN
```

Comment: added bonus material - lunch break :)

Comment: ahhhhh ok i see, yeahhh that should be fine i appreciate your help mn :) Thanks!

Comment: Qucik question with the parsing there is there a way how to parse however not stop parsing i.e if you look for "E""V" but "E""V" are not next to each other it will cause the parsing to fail is there a way how not to cause the parsing to fail?